# Cannot access iframe DOM elements without first selecting it with developer tools

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension which accesses the video elements on web pages. This is the [iframe and child video element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu5RQ.png). 
When attempting to get access to the iframe DOM using (this is in the content script running on the page):

```
function GetIframeDocument(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById("vilos-player");
    var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var videoElement = doc.getElementByid("player_html5_api");
}
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.crunchyroll.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at <anonymous>:1:21
```

However, if I go into chrome developer tools and make the video element a global variable ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3kwJ.png)). I can then apply javascript to the element in the console without running into the cross-origin frame error ([as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXTYY.png)).

How can I access the video element in my script without running into the error? If I can access it in the console and it can be seen in the page elements in developer tools.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include an example of the code that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what you need to do, but obviously get a link to the video. 
Recommend that you inject your javascript using a chrome extension. During the creation of the extension, set the parameter

```
all_frames = true
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

then your code will be on all pages and on iframe too.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could have my content script run separately within frames on the page.

Answer (score 0):

As we can read in [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

> The HTML Inline Frame element () represents a nested browsing context, embedding another HTML page into the current one.

So, iframe element has its own window object, and for access it you can use predefined method **contentWindow()**.

See method [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow) and [W3Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp).

Comment: My original post was a bit confusing so i cleared it up, I was using content window to try to access the iframe but it would throw the cross-domain error. It did not give me this error when i selected the video element inside the iframe from developer tools and acted on it in the console.